# I can't turn off my Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: shutdown

I am using a Compaq Presario C700. Before upgrading from Ubuntu 12.10 everything was fine, but since I switched to Ubuntu 13.04, I can't shutdown my system in any way. The only thing I could do is hold the power button until it shuts down on its own.

I have tried using the terminal to shutdown, but it's no use. When I click on the shutdown button on the title bar, there is no option for shutdown. The only thing I could see is Lock Screen and Log Out. What should I do?

Comment: i have tried it but no use please help

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command for shut down pc:-

```
$ sudo shutdown -P now

$ sudo shutdown -h 0

$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: this is also not working please help

Comment: which kind of problem you are facing , any error or black screen, please specify.